# How to store data in RDS after a User/Media item have been successfully created through Cognito/S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Currently, I am building a React Native project and I am using AWS Amplify as the main source of communication to AWS. I have Cognito and S3 set up and I am able to successfully create Users (Cognito) and Videos (S3); however, when an user/media item is successfully created I want to store their reference within the MySQL database that we have created. I explored the idea about using triggers to store the data, but those do not send a response back to the front-end and I want the frontend to behave appropriately depending on if the user/media item was successfully inserted into both cognito/s3 AND the database. For example, if a user is created in cognito but for some reason is not created in the database I want to be able to detect that and display an error message on the front-end and remove the account from cognito.

This could potentially be the wrong way to do this so any type of guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You can try using SNS with web socket to send message from server. Or you can call the database after an interval to check if the data has been updated.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/